# "on here" vs "in here" for websites

Tags: prepositions, differences

I'm wondering whether to use "on here" or "in here" to refer to the current website.

> Be skeptical of what you read on here.

versus

> Be skeptical of what you read in here.

Is there any difference? Which is correct? I know that I can avoid this discussion altogether by writing "Be skeptical of what you read here" instead, but I'm curious about "in here" vs "on here" for websites.

Comment: Without  in and on, it goes fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think it comes down to context. Some websites, particularly where small(ish) or common interest groups hang out with each other, feel to users like a place they inhabit, so "in here" is appropriate for them. Similarly for chat servers. For most websites, "here" or “here on [site name]” would make more sense. I think most people prefer "on this [web]site" to "on here", which sounds slightly awkward to my ears.

Answer (score -1):

"Be skeptical of what you read on here" is correct for this website.
"On here" refers to like websites and stuff, "In here" refers to places, and being "in" somewhere. (Sorry, I know my wording's not professional; I'm in high school, but I'm trying to help you out the best I can here.) :)